# Controlling a 220V European outlet from Arduino

Tags: high-voltage, outlet

I want to use an Arduino to control my 220V outlet.

I have searched the web and stack a couple of hours and all I found was [this product](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10747) from Sparkfun and Adafruit, but it does only take 110V and it is an American outlet.

Neither the Weemo will work here in Denmark.

Our outlets in Europe (Denmark) look like this.

[image: Europe outlet]

I want to avoid to work with high voltage (and possible a fire). How?

Comment: It is a very happy looking outlet.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany hee hee

Answer (score 1):

I share Andys idea of modifying an existing remote controlled socket.

Nexa has a couple of remote sockets that works well in Sweden. Probably works in Denmark too... :)

http://www.pricerunner.dk/sp/nexa.html

The outdoor version works really well with heavy loads and at low temperatures. They are available in a pack with a remote.

Answer (score 0):

One of these: -

[image]

Plus, one of these: -

[image]

And a little bit of ingenuity interfacing the "remote" to the Arduino should work fine. Maybe if you look for radio controlled AC outlet sockets you can find a danish one.

Answer (score 0):

Consider taking a standard extension cord for your country,
cuting it in half and splicing it into a
["PowerSwitch Tail 240 Kit for 200-240vac mains (PN PSTK-240)"](http://www.powerswitchtail.com/Pages/PSTKKit.aspx).

[image]

Comment: Had not seen that they had their own website, that could be a solution! I am just a little sad that they based in North America.